# Creating instance of another model within Django model manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two django models defined in my models.py file - Employee model and ContactBook model as shown below:

```
class Employee(FatCrocBaseModel):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects = EmployeeManager()

class ContactBook(FatCrocBaseModel):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I am trying to create a custom ModelManager called EmployeeManager where the ContactBook object is automatically created for each employee (one-to-one relationship) each time a new Employee is created.  The code for the ModelManager that I came up with is below:

```
class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
        employee = super(EmployeeManager, self).create(*args, **kwargs)
        ContactBook.objects.create(employee=employee)
        return employee
```

I'm a new programmer in Django and would like to know if the above is an acceptable practice in Django (create ContactBook from EmployeeManager).  Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Why have separate models? If a `ContactBook` is created for every `Employee` why not merge both models into one?

Comment: If you do need to create a Model (ex:ContactBook) whenever another model (Employee) is created, one way to do it is using django signals.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to proceed with incorporating both models into one. The second model serves no real purpose in this case.